# Error when creating outlet in AppCode

Tags: ios, swift, nullpointerexception, appcode

This is the error I get when I try to create a new connection from a view to the component tree by clicking and dragging. I get this error even before I release my mouse button which seems very weird.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.appcode.designer.propertyTable.connections.ios.StoryboardConnectionInfo.addPresentingSegues(StoryboardConnectionInfo.java:108)
    at com.intellij.appcode.designer.propertyTable.connections.ios.StoryboardConnectionInfo.addConnections(StoryboardConnectionInfo.java:56)
    at com.intellij.appcode.designer.propertyTable.connections.ios.IOSXibConnectionManager.getConnectionProperties(IOSXibConnectionManager.java:103)
    at com.intellij.appcode.designer.propertyTable.connections.ios.StoryboardConnectionManager.getConnectionProperties(StoryboardConnectionManager.java:47)
    at com.intellij.appcode.designer.model.storyboard.AbstractV3ModelParser.getConnectionProperties(AbstractV3ModelParser.java:55)
    at com.intellij.appcode.designer.model.RadXmlComponent.getConnectionProperties(RadXmlComponent.java:270)
    at com.intellij.appcode.designer.propertyTable.connections.ConnectionTool$3.resultFilter(ConnectionTool.java:244)
    at com.intellij.designer.componentTree.TreeEditableArea.findTarget(TreeEditableArea.java:210)
    at com.intellij.appcode.designer.propertyTable.connections.ConnectionTool.handleDragInProgress(ConnectionTool.java:232)
    at com.intellij.designer.designSurface.tools.InputTool.mouseDrag(InputTool.java:302)
    at com.intellij.designer.designSurface.tools.ToolProvider.processMouseEvent(ToolProvider.java:93)
    at com.intellij.designer.designSurface.ComponentGlassLayer.mouseDragged(ComponentGlassLayer.java:101)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseDragged(AWTEventMulticaster.java:303)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6462)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.superProcessMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3299)
    at javax.swing.Autoscroller.actionPerformed(Autoscroller.java:159)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:291)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:221)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:577)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:384)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```